# Keycloak Unknown Provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak.js for interaction with Keycloak and getting below error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthProvider <- Auth <- authInterceptor <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile
```

With below code:

```
module.factory('authInterceptor', ['$q', 'Auth', function($q, Auth) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if (Auth.authz.token) {
        Auth.authz.updateToken(5).success(function() {
          config.headers = config.headers || {};
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + Auth.authz.token;

          deferred.resolve(config);
        }).error(function() {
          deferred.reject('Failed to refresh token');
        });
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
}]);

module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
}]);
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

I am also including keycloak.js in my index.html which is inserted with Bower

I also have below Auth factory instantiated inside dom ready:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function($http) {
  var keycloakAuth = new Keycloak('keycloak.json');
  auth.loggedIn = false;

  keycloakAuth.init().success(function () {
    auth.loggedIn = true;
    auth.authz = keycloakAuth;
    auth.logoutUrl = keycloakAuth.authServerUrl + "/realms/demo/tokens/logout?redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000";
    module.factory('Auth', function () {
      return auth;
    });
  }).error(function () {
    window.location.reload();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are instantiating "Auth" on dom ready, but the dependecy injector is trying to inject before the dom ready (simplifying).

The question is why on dom ready?

here are two examples:

http://jsbin.com/lulin/1/edit
(with on dom ready definition, not working, same error)

http://jsbin.com/wajeho/2/edit
(without on dom ready definition,working)

---

EDIT:

You have to do something like this:
http://jsbin.com/xusiva/1/edit?html,js,console

I'm difining the factory outside the domready, and inside the controller after domready i'm using it.

Comment: This is on dom ready so I can make it authenticate immediately. I'm not sure if this needs to be under index.js config function instead

Comment: the problem is even when I remove dom ready I'm getting same error

Comment: In your example, why does it work when you add [] in the second parameter in module but when I remove it doesn't work?

Comment: The empty array after the name of the module is the list of modules on which my module depends on. Is not optional. If your module has no dependencies you must put empty array.

Comment: What i'm trying to say about domready is that you are defining a factory after the fire of this event. The factory i'm speaking of is "Auth". That factory should be defined elsewhere and consumed after domready.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, so far for what I can tell is that the example of Keycloak is running angular 1.2, and you are probably using the latest 1.3.
If you try Keycloak angular example with angular 1.2 it works, but when you try it with 1.3 you get that error.

I have being reading about this and it has to do with the interceptors, the way they are declared in angular 1.3 is different.
Also, responseInterceptors are completly deprecated in angular 1.3.

Comment: Stumbled on this SO question exactly for this reason : keycloak github repo Angular JS example is for AngularJS 1.2. Working on a 1.3+ version, will PR on keycloak repository when ready

Comment: I am having the exact same issues and I was wondering if you've got it working with 1.3 and if you posted the code anywhere. It would be of much help for me, thanks!

Comment: I have an example working on angular 1.5.11 and keycloak 9.0.0 from a few years agoo